# XPM inline editing of multivalued embedded field is not working

Tags: experience-manager, dd4t

In our project we are using a Schema (FAQ) for frequently asked questions. It has a text field heading (for question) and an embedded field paragraph (for Answer) field.

Below is the DD4T Component Template code that we are using -

```
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-right-8 faq-contant">
    <div class="">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-space">
            <h2>
                <xpm:editable model="${FAQ}" field="heading">
                    <c:out value="${FAQ.heading}" />
                </xpm:editable>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <divclass="">
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-space m_top_22">
            <c:forEach var="paragraph" items="${FAQ.paragraph}" varStatus="status" >
                <xpm:editable model="${FAQ}" field="paragraph" index="${status.count}">
                    <c:out value="${paragraph.content}" escapeXml="false" />
                </xpm:editable>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
    </div>
    </c:if>
```

Now when we are accessing that page using Experience Manager, the `heading` field is working fine but the `paragraph` is not editable.

The JSON ouput of the page -

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-space">
    <h2>                    
        <span><!-- Start Component Field: {
"XPath" : "tcm:Content/custom:FAQ/custom:heading[1]"
} -->
            Put your heading Here                   
        </span>                 
    </h2>               
</div>
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-space m_top_22">
   <span><!-- Start Component Field: {
"XPath" : "tcm:Metadata/custom:Metadata/custom:paragraph[1]/custom:paragraph[1]"
} -->
        Here is the description             
   </span>  
</div>
```

Comment: Sayantan, do you also have the JSON output for the paragraph field? Knowing the Xpath can help troubleshoot the field.

Answer (score 2):

The model name specified under the "xpm:editable" tag was wrong, so it is generating the wrong XPATH for that embedded field.Previously it was pointing to the model for the current schema. Now I have changed the model value and point it to the model used for embedded schema.

Previously the code was -

```
 <divclass="">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-space m_top_22">
        <c:forEach var="paragraph" items="${FAQ.paragraph}" varStatus="status" >
            <xpm:editable model="${FAQ}" field="paragraph" index="${status.count}">
                <c:out value="${paragraph.content}" escapeXml="false" />
            </xpm:editable>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated code is -

```
 <divclass="">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-space m_top_22">
        <c:forEach var="paragraph" items="${FAQ.paragraph}" varStatus="status" >
            <xpm:editable model="${paragraph}" field="paragraph" index="${status.count}">
                <c:out value="${paragraph.content}" escapeXml="false" />
            </xpm:editable>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</div>
```